# doing same operation on multiple variables using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and am working with 18 pandas dataframes at once. I want to do the same operation on all the dataframes but havent seemed to find a one line bit of code to do it for me. I get what I want but I do individual lines of code for all 18 variables just now.

example

```
    a = [1,3; 2,1; 3,4]
    b = [1,6; 2,9; 3,2]
    c = [1,5; 2,8; 3,9]
```

I want to create a 3rd column in all these variables, which is column 2 multiplied by lets say 4. What would be the most efficient way to write a code to do the same operation for all the variables at once so that my outputs has variables a,b,c with 3 columns, with the third being column 2 x 4

Comment: Just put all your dataframes in a list, then loop over the list, then do the thing. Right?

Comment: Will that work, @Jazim?

Comment: I think i semi get what you mean but would you mind writing it in code form based of my example to better understand what you mean

Comment: `for df in [df1, df2, df3]:`? Or whatever your 18 frames are called

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple loop and do your thing for each dataframe:

```py
for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, ...]:
    # do your thing with df, e.g.:
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear - you already have 3 columns listed and you shouldn't be using semicolons in your list (syntax errors).

Much to what another user said: Put all of your dataframes *names* in a list and then write a quick for loop to do that. As a brief example:

```
df_list = ['df1','df2',....'dfn']

for i in df_list:
    globals()[i][2] = globals()[i].iloc[1]*4
```

This should iterate through your list of dataframes, multiplying the 2nd column by the number 4, and then storing it your third column (overwriting what was there before).

Comment: thats great thanks and it worked a treat. I just wanted to ask, what if i wanted to multiply rows 1-5 by 4 but rows 6-10 by 2, if my examples had 10 rows using your method. Ive been trying it a few methods and seem to keep getting errors so thought I would ask.

Comment: You would need to add a few more sub-"for loops" to your call. Something like:

`
for i in df_list:
    for j in range(0,4):
        globals()[i][j] = globals()[i].iloc[j]*4
    for k in range(5,9):
        globals()[i][jk] = glbals()[i].iloc[k]*2
`

But at that point, you are better off defining a function and running it through a list of data frames for the amount (4,2, etc.) and ranges (0-4, 5-9) (Also, remember that python uses zero indexing :-) )